# Compare non identical objects with same value

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists,both in different formats but same content.
For example, doing a simple print command for the 1st elements of the list does the following:

```
prefix_txt[0]=SEF00
prefix_confluence[0]=[u'SEF00']
```

I get the 'u' here is due to the encoding..

The prefix_confluence is being parsed by a HTML parser this way:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(sample,'html.parser')
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[2:171]:
   prefix_confluence.append(row.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[0:1])
```

Now, how do I compare and show that these 2 list elements are in fact equal in content? 
I have tried this:

```
new=str(prefix_confluence[0]).strip('[u'']')
if(prefix_txt[0]==new):
        print "They are same."
```

But they dont display the print message due to obvious reasons.
How can I make them equal? I also tried join, concatenation but was not able to make it work.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are not equal.  You have a string on one hand and a list with one element, which is a Unicode string.  How are you populating the data for `prefix_confluence`?

Comment: In `prefix_txt[0]=SEF00` what does `SEF00` refer to? Or is this supposed to be the string `'SEF00'`?

Comment: @eddiem please check out the edited version

Comment: SEF00 is just some name. Its not a string. For example doing prefix_txt[1] will give me SEF01 etc @elethan

Comment: @elethan dont delete your answer. It worked.

Comment: @AnuragJoshi I updated it. Did it work with the two indexes, or with only one? i.e., `new = prefix_confluence[0]` or `new = prefix_confluence[0][0]`, I am a little confused.

Comment: 2 indexes. Can you please explain what I was missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `prefix_txt[0]` is a string `'SEF00'`, and `prefix_confluence[0]` is a list containing a unicode version of that same string `[u'SEF00']`, then you should be able to do the following:

```
new = prefix_confluence[0][0]
if(prefix_txt[0] == new):
        print "They are same."
```

When you do `new = str(prefix_confluence[0]).strip('[u'']')` you will get the string `"'SEF00'"`, which as you can see is slightly different from the string `'SEF00'`. Instead, you can get the string out of the list by indexing the list: `prefix_confluence[0][0]`, which will give you `u'SEF00'`. Although this looks different from `'SEF00'`, in Python 2.x they are seen as equal; i.e., `'SEF00' == u'SEF00'` is `True`, although their types are different and they do not point to the same object:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = u'foo'
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'unicode'>
```

And for completeness, the same solution will work in Python 3.x, although what is happening is slightly different. In Python 3, all strings are unicode by default, so not only are `'SEF00'` and `u'SEF00'` equal in Python 3, they should generally point to the same object as far as I know:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = u'foo'
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what I was missing or where I was going wrong?

Comment: @AnuragJoshi, no problem, give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So if I was to use this in Python 3.x this would not work right? Any suggestions on what could we be a solution to this problem for Python 3.x?

Comment: @AnuragJoshi happy to help! This solution should work for Python 3.x as well.

Comment: @AnuragJoshi no problem. See my final update which points out a few interesting things with regards to Python 3